# Strange error for onEditorAction : "unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls"

Tags: android

I have a **EditText** in my fragment and when I perform enter or any action that count like enter, I want to do something. But I had some problems with the `onEditorAction` ids of `KeyEvent` or `actionId` so I follow another thread in this site that helps me a lot for a lot of things to do this :

```
inputSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView exampleView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                        event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
                             //do something
          }
          return true;
      }
});
```

But when I do this with all of this conditions, my app crash and output me this in logcat:

```
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/View(26569): hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
05-05 15:56:05.195: W/dalvikvm(26569): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fde48)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569): Process: com.myapp PID: 26569
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.myapp.SomeFragment$3.onEditorAction(SomeFragment.java:148)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4395)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:297)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
05-05 15:56:05.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And when I keep only the `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` in conditions the app does not crash, but does not do anything, and logcat output only this :

```
 05-05 15:56:05.195: E/View(26569): hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
```

I have searched on Google but didn't find something convincing for this very strange error for me.
For me and others who maybe are going to face the same problems, I would like some help on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your exception is:

```
hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
```

in your `TextView`, use the methods

[**android:imeOptions**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

and

[**android:imeActionId**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionId)

Comment: I got the same error message ("unmatched pair...") in a completely different context (having set convertView.setTransientState(true/false) in adapter.getView())

I'm completely at a loss what that method setting / getting a boolean actually increments or decrements.

Comment: I've seen "E/View: hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls" errors in the log sometimes when using EditText or AutoCompleteTextView fields, with no calls to setTransientState() or similar in my code.  The app doesn't crash due to these errors and seems to work fine from the user's perspective.  These seem to be internal errors from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The hasTransientState error is not the exception and might be unrelated.

The OP's exception is `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.myapp.SomeFragment$3.onEditorAction(SomeFragment.java:148)`.
Presumably line 148 is the `if` statement, and the exception is probably caused by the event parameter being null.

"KeyEvent: If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null." from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html